# Visual Studio metadata filenames are inconsistent

Tags: visual-studio, cygwin, robocopy

The following seems to be a Visual Studio 2017 bug. I will post it here to see if there are alternative explanations.

Sometimes Visual Studio will create a file with a file name ending in `.cache` and sometimes it will end with `.Cache`. The difference is only in the aspect of capitalization.

An example is this file, starting at a Visual Studio project directory.

`../ListEditor/obj/Debug/ListEditor.csproj.GenerateResource.cache`

If there is something in the operation of Visual Studio that can avoid this bug I would like to know.

The following is "background" information about why this matters to me and is not essential to my inquiry.

This inconsistency in the file name is has no effect on the operation of Visual Studio and Windows because the operating system is case-insensitive. However, it does have a subtle effect in the intersection of `robocopy` and `cygwin` and `diff --recursive`.

Suppose a backup is made and verified as follows.

`robocopy c:\users\joe\documents d:\windowsbackup\documents /XJ /MIR`

`diff --recursive --brief /cygdrive/c/Users/joe/Documents /cygdrive/d/windowsbackup/Documents`

robocopy's economizing heuristic is that a copy is needed if there is a change to the size or timestamp of a file. In other words, robocopy is not perfect, but the verification is intended to catch robocopy's mistakes. These mistakes are admittedly unlikely when nobody is messing with the system clock and programs are not back-dating. **However, when a large quantity of data is copied performing a verification might be considered prudent in order to detect corruption.** Visual Studio needlessly alternating between `.cache` and `.Cache` creates a problem for the verification. Since the `diff` verification happens in `cygwin`, which is case-sensitive, the following will be output.

`Only in /cygdrive/c/users/joe/Documents/source/repos/Auna4/ListEditor/obj/Debug: ListEditor.csproj.GenerateResource.cache`

`Only in /cygdrive/d/windowsbackup/Documents/source/repos/Auna4/ListEditor/obj/Debug: ListEditor.csproj.GenerateResource.Cache`

So `diff` found a difference but it is not the kind of difference we care about and furthermore it declines to verify the file contents to detect corruption. One solution involves writing a script to collect the `diff` output and pass it to cygwin `cmp` to do the content verification that cygwin `diff` declined to do. (Diff is used because it supports recursion but cmp does not.)

`cmp /cygdrive/c/users/joe/Documents/source/repos/Auna4/ListEditor/obj/Debug/ListEditor.csproj.GenerateResource.cache /cygdrive/d/windowsbackup/Documents/source/repos/Auna4/ListEditor/obj/Debug/ListEditor.csproj.GenerateResource.Cache`

**The bottom line**: robocopy is probably okay when there is no human nor programmatic altering of the system clock but for large amounts of data detecting corruption is nice to have but not readily attainable with the "default" tools given the Visual Studio file name bug. cygwin already stretches the definition of "default" tool. For my purposes, the most popular system is often the default choice if I am concerned about bugs and support. I think cygwin was very popular before Microsoft added the Linux subsystem to Windows. (At the moment, I cannot remember why I used cygwin instead of the Windows 10 Linux subsystem.)

Edit: Note this is also happening with the 'MyProgram.exe.config' file which more recently appears as 'MyProgram.exe.Config'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a question here except to say that Visual Studio is sometimes inconsistent about filename casing for these `.cache` directories (annoying indeed!)

One way you can make this play better with Cygwin is to "mount" that directory in Cygwin with `posix=0` (which just makes Cygwin treat files/directories under the mount target as case-insensitive: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mount.html).

In other words (as annoying as it is to have to do this) edit `/etc/fstab` to mount the parent directory of your Visual Studio projects with the `posix=0` option so that it properly treats files as case-insensitive.  While I haven't encountered this specific problem, I've generally found that to be the best option for working with Windows applications under Cygwin.

Comment: This seemed like a solution but my interpretation of the default configuration in /etc/fstab is that the setting is already case-insensitive. `none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0`. Perhaps `diff` does not comply with the case-insensitive selection.